Keyboard shortcuts for superscript/subscript
I wanted to know if there are keyboard shortcuts for superscript and subscript (already tried CTRL plus = and CTRL plus SHIFT plus +, for instance) in math equations in Microsoft Word (I am using the latest version of it).

Microsoft reports CTRL + = and CTRL + SHIFT+ + are right (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-text-as-superscript-or-subscript-in-word-507cdffd-8169-4872-96ec-909ea5888dc6) Do you have any shortcuts defined on your computer that may be conflicting with these? Are you running PowerToys?

Windows or Mac?  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/create-a-list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft/7952be51-6a8e-4382-994c-e6632ba4cf35?tm=1589698042191

I don't think there are shorcuts that do the same as the ctrl-shift-+ and ctrl-shift-_ superscript and subscript shortcuts, and nor do I think you can create them.
There is a difference between "math text" and "other text" in Equation Editor.
For math text (which is what you get when you just type in Equation editor), the normal Superscript and Subscript are not available at all. i.e. if you select some math text and press ctrl-D to display the Font dialog box, you will see that the superscript and subscript options are greyed out. And that is presumably because you are supposed to superscript math text by preceding it with ^ and subscript math text by preceding it with _ - which you doubtless already know. You could probably make a shortcut that would run a VBA macro insert the correct characters to superscript/subscript selected math text characters, but getting that to do what "the right thing" in all circumstances would be quite difficult, I think. (e.g., suppose you had the text abcdef, you selected cd and pressed a shortcut to run a superscript macro, it could probably change the text to ab^cd ef , but what if you had other math formatting in the selected text?
For "other text", i.e. the sort that you can enter when you click the Equations tab, COnversions group, Text button (which looks like ab Text), the ctrl-shift-+ and ctrl-shift-_ keys do not work. Assigning different shortcuts to the relevant Commands does not work. However, if you press ctrl-D to display the Font dialog box you can check the superscript or subscript options.
Word will even let you record a macro while doing that, but when you run it, you get an error message, number 6243, saying "This character style is not allowed inside math"
Putting the Superscript command on the Quick Access Toolbar does not work either - it's greyed out whichever kind of text is selected in the Equation.
